# Gradle clean is considered up-to-date

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have written a custom plugin **which does nothing with the clean task**. My plugin applies **LifecycleBasePlugin** (so it will have build, check, clean etc).

If I call *gradle clean* it is said to be up to date and nothing happens. I suppose from the source it should delete the build directory /project.getBuildDir()/ where I also put my built files to.

The output of *gradle -im clean*:

```
Selected primary task 'clean' from project :
Tasks to be executed: [task ':clean']
:clean (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:clean
 Skipping task ':clean' as task onlyIf is false.
:clean SKIPPED
:clean (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.011 secs.
```

I have also tried to delete .gradle.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your `build.gradle` file. `gradle clean` should, by default, delete your build directory. But depending upon what you did with your build directory in your script, you may have confused it.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute command below

```
gradle build --refresh-dependencies
```

or

delete .gradle folder in your user folder and compile again.

in linux or Mac,

```
~/.gradle
```

in windows

```
C:User¥your-id¥.gradle
```

please try.

Comment: Thank you, I will try these. It seems to be very useful as I have only tried to delete .gradle in my project folder.